# Developing custom kendo ui widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, custom-controls

How can I develop a custom widget behaving like this sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/anilca/u2HF7/

[Here is](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-10-16/inheriting_from_custom_widgets) my kickstart reading, but I could not find out how to define the templates of dropdownlists and link them together by change events.

```
(function($) { 
    var kendo = window.kendo,
    ui = kendo.ui,
    Widget = ui.Widget;

    var Editable = Widget.extend({
    init: function(element, options) {
       var that = this;

       Widget.fn.init.call(this, element, options);

       that._create();
    },
    options: {
       name: "Editable",
       value: " ",
       editable: false
    },
    _create: function() {
       var that = this;
       // create dropdowns from templates and append them to DOM 
    },
    _templates: {
       dropDown: "?"
    }
   });
   ui.plugin(Editable);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the blog you linked, simply do what he did - define your templates then create the drop-downs in your `_create()` function. It is not necessary to use the `kendo.template()` function on each drop down list, as it does not bind objects as well as you think it would. Instead, the key is to use `kendo.bind()` and pass in the `options` as your view model.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zefudehi/1/edit?js,output) is a JsBin working example.

```
// listen for doc ready because this is js bin and my code is not really "in" the HTML
// where I can control it.
$(function() {
  // wrap the widget in a closure. Not necessary in doc ready, but a good practice
  (function($) { 
    var kendo = window.kendo,
        ui = kendo.ui,
        Widget = ui.Widget,
        periods = [{ text: "PERIOD: YEAR", value: "YEAR" }, { text: "PERIOD: QUARTER", value: "QUARTER" }],
        quarters = [{ text: "1. Quarter", value: 1 }, { text: "2. Quarter", value: 2 }, { text: "3. Quarter", value: 3 }, { text: "4. Quarter", value: 4 }],
        years = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014];

    var LinkedDropDowns = Widget.extend({
      init: function(element, options) {
        var that = this;
        Widget.fn.init.call(that, element, options);      
        that._create();
      },
      options: {
        name: "LinkedDropDowns",
        period: "YEAR",
        periods: periods,
        year: 2011,
        years: years,
        yearVisible: true,
        quarter: 1,
        quarters: quarters,
        quarterVisible: false,
        onPeriodChange: function(e) {
          switch(e.sender.value()) {
            case "YEAR":
              this.set("yearVisible", true);
              this.set("quarterVisible", false);
              break;
            case "QUARTER":
              this.set("yearVisible", true);
              this.set("quarterVisible", true);
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        },
        onYearChange: function(e) {
          alert(e.sender.value());
        },
        onQuarterChange: function(e) {
          alert(e.sender.value());
        }
      },
      _create: function() {
        var that = this;

        // create dropdowns from templates and append them to DOM
        that.periodDropDown = $(that._templates.periodDropDown);
        that.yearDropDown = $(that._templates.yearDropDown);
        that.quarterDropDown = $(that._templates.quarterDropDown);

        // append all elements to the DOM
        that.element.append(that.periodDropDown)
                    .append(that.yearDropDown)
                    .append(that.quarterDropDown);

        kendo.bind(that.element, that.options);
      },
      _templates: {
        periodDropDown: "<input id='period' data-role='dropdownlist' data-text-field='text' data-value-field='value' data-bind='value: period, source: periods, events: { change: onPeriodChange }' />",
        yearDropDown: "<input id='year' data-role='dropdownlist' data-bind='visible: yearVisible, value: year, source: years, events: { change: onYearChange }' style='width: 90px' />",
        quarterDropDown: "<input id='quarter' data-role='dropdownlist' data-text-field='text' data-value-field='value' data-bind='visible: quarterVisible, value: quarter, source: quarters, events: { change: onQuarterChange }' style='width: 110px' />"
      }
    });

    ui.plugin(LinkedDropDowns);
  })(jQuery);

  $('#dropdowns').kendoLinkedDropDowns();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now everything become more clear. Is it possible to use it in mvvm convention? ( for ex: by just typing: '<div id="dropdowns" data-role="linkeddropdowns" data-period="YEAR" data-bind="year: selectedYear"></div>' )