# Kendo UI NumericTextBox percentage format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My problem is very similar to what is explained in this question:
[KendoNumericTextBox percentage formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883554/kendonumerictextbox-percentage-formatting)

But I'm using ASP.NET MVC Wrappers to render the `NumericTextBox`.

I have the following editor template to render the Widget:

```
@model double?
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<double>(m => m)
.Format("{0:P2}")
.Min(0)
.Max(1)
.Step(0.01)
)
```

But what is happening is that (examples):

- Value show when widget IS focused:  0.01 -> Value show when widget IS NOT focused:  10,00%
- Value show when widget IS focused:  0.63 -> Value show when widget IS NOT focused:  63,00%
- Value show when widget IS focused:  0,6345 -> Value show when widget IS NOT focused:  63,00%
- Value show when widget IS focused:  5 -> Value show when widget IS NOT focused:  100,00%

What I would like is somethinh like this:

- Value show when widget IS focused:  10 -> Value show when widget IS NOT focused:  10,00%
- Value show when widget IS focused:  63 -> Value show when widget IS NOT focused:  63,00%
- Value show when widget IS focused:  63,45 -> Value show when widget IS NOT focused:  63,45%

but in the database I need to store a value between 0 and 1. This is the reason I have `....Min(0).Max(1)...`

How could I achieve this using the MVC Wrapper?

Comment: so you need to Display.

Entered value us 0.01 -> needs to show 0.01%
its correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I came up with was:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<double>(m => m)
    .Format("##.00 \\%")
    .Min(0)
    .Step(1)
    .Decimals(2)
)
```

After, in the controller, I convert to [0,1].

Answer (score 2):

Use this format for your widget

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<double>(m => m)
    .Format("#.## '%'")
    .Min(0)
    .Max(1)
    .Step(0.01)
)
```

add more `'#'` behind `'.'` to have more decimals.

Answer (score 0):

would you please try this,

$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
   format: "# '%'"
});

for more information find this link

http://dojo.telerik.com/AKODe
or
[Click Here](http://jsbin.com/ezuquv/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: In your first solution, if I put 6.3, it shows 6% on focus out... I would like 6,3%. The second solution, I need to save a number between 0 and 1 despite showing a value between 0 and 100% (with decimal places). So it is not working.